# which jar needed for org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext in eclipse for scala

Tags: scala

I am using below code.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

object SqlContextSparkScala {

 def main (args: Array[String]) {
    val sc =SparkContext
    val sqlcontext = new SQLContext(sc)
  }

}
```

I am getting error like spark is not member of org.apache.
I am writing this java code in eclipse IDE.Please suggest appropriate jar.

Comment: Have you followed any of the guides on how to set up Spark and Eclipse? For instance, http://freecontent.manning.com/wp-content/uploads/how-to-start-developing-spark-applications-in-eclipse.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Please include spark-core_2.10-1.4.1.jar

If you are using maven please include below mentioned dependency

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```